# window.innerWidth won't work with internet explorer windows mobile

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, mobile, windows-7, windows-mobile

So i am simply wanting to output the current viewport of the document

```
$('#dimensions').text(window.innerWidth + 'x' + window.innerWidth);
```

Does not work and comes back as undefinedxundefined in internet explorer mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer, i shouldn't have been looking for 'windows mobile' and just look for normal Internet Explorer:

`document.body.clientWidth`